# How to fix: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion

Tags: rust, lifetime

I managed to run into a lifetime issue again that I seem to be unable to resolve on my own.

The compiler tells me *cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion*

[image]

I tried to follow the compilers suggestion and introduced the lifetime annotations in the `handle_request` method.

```
fn handle_request<'a>(&self, req: &Request, res: &'a mut ResponseWriter) {


    fn set_headers(req: &Request, res: &mut ResponseWriter) {
        //probably not important for the example 
    }

    match &req.request_uri {
        &AbsolutePath(ref url) => {
            match self.router.match_route(req.method.clone(), url.clone()) {
                Some(route_result) => { 
                    set_headers(req, res); 

                    let floor_req = request::Request{
                        origin: req,
                        params: route_result.params.clone()
                    };

                    let floor_res = response::Response{
                        origin: res
                    };

                    (route_result.route.handler)(floor_req, &mut floor_res);
                },
                None => {}
            }
        },
        _ => set_headers(req, res)
    }
}
```

I had the code working before but now I wanted to wrap the `http::server::ResponseWriter` in my own `Response` struct. I did exactly the same for the `Request` before but in terms of lifetimes the case seems to be slightly different. Maybe because it's a `&mut` instead of just a simple `&` reference.

This is my **`ResponseWriter`** struct.

```
use http;

///A container for the response
pub struct Response<'a> {
    ///the original `http::server::ResponseWriter`
    pub origin: &'a mut http::server::ResponseWriter<'a>,
}
```

Just incase any Samaritan wants to compile the code locally, I pushed it into the *lifetime_crazyness* branch here: https://github.com/cburgdorf/Floor/commits/lifetime_craziness

Just run `make floor` to compile it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, so I pulled down your code to try and compile it. Indeed, if we take a look at the definition of your `Response` struct, we see this:

```
pub struct Response<'a> {
    ///the original `http::server::ResponseWriter`
    pub origin: &'a mut http::server::ResponseWriter<'a>,
}
```

From the compiler's perspective, this definition claims that the lifetime of the pointer to a `http::server::ResponseWriter` is *the same* as whatever lifetime is inside of `http::server::ResponseWriter`. I don't see any particular reason why this should be true, and it looks like the compiler can't either. So to fix it, you need to introduce another lifetime parameter so that you allow for the possibility that the lifetimes are distinct:

```
pub struct Response<'a, 'b> {
    ///the original `http::server::ResponseWriter`
    pub origin: &'a mut http::server::ResponseWriter<'b>,
}
```

Here's the fix in a PR for you: https://github.com/BurntSushi/Floor/commit/127962b9afc2779c9103c28f37e52e8d292f9ff2

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up the question. I meant the `response`. But yep, you figured it out. I'll update the question later. I'm on mobile. Have to re-read your answer later. Thanks for your help. I'll be honored to have you listed as a contributor to Floor :)

Comment: Thanks again! I corrected my question and also your answer. However, I have a follow up question to that ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24292831/what-do-these-both-structs-differ-in-the-way-they-are-affected-by-lifetimes

Comment: I rebased the commit to be more semantical but made you the commit author because you helped me with it. If however, you *don't* want to be associated with the commit because you think it's utter nonsense, tell me and I make me the author.

Comment: Ah, there is the commit https://github.com/cburgdorf/Floor/commit/dde2d3be262b76c80950a858bc1a62f153fc72da