# Why do these both structs differ in the way they are affected by lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is a follow up question to: [How to fix: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291288/how-to-fix-cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-automatic-coercion).

I wonder why do these both structs differ in the way they are affected by lifetimes.

**Example 1**

```
use http;

pub struct Request<'a> {
    pub origin: &'a http::server::Request,
}
```

**Example 2**

```
use http;

pub struct Response<'a, 'b> {
    pub origin: &'a mut http::server::ResponseWriter<'b>,
}
```

They look pretty much similar to me except that the second one holds a mutable reference whereas the first one holds an immutable reference.

However, for *Example 2* I can't just use a lifetime for the reference. I **must** give a lifetime for the struct as well.

So, I wonder is there something *inside* the struct that causes such behavior or is it really because the one in the second example is a mutable reference. And if so, why exactly does that cause that.

Comment: "However, for Example 2 I can't just use a lifetime for the reference. I must give a lifetime for the struct as well." You mean that you can't omit `<'b>` after `ResponseWriter`? In this case it happens because `ResponseWriter` is parameterized by a lifetime, while `Request` is not. It is similar to that you have to write `Option<int>` with a parameter but `String` without one.

Comment: If you inspect the definition of `ResponseWriter`, you will find that it contains a reference. I'm guessing that it's this ResponseWriter: http://www.rust-ci.org/chris-morgan/rust-http/doc/http/server/response/struct.ResponseWriter.html

Comment: Ah, brilliant. It's parameterized by a lifetime in it's definition. So I have to take that into account. Makes sense! If anyone cares to add it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for automatic coercion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291288/how-to-fix-cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-automatic-coercion)

Comment: (As a general rule, if you have just a slight extra question—this was just a request for clarification—it’s best to keep it in the same question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&'a T` means that you have a reference to a `T` object which is valid for the lifetime`'a`.

`T<'b>` means a `T` object containing an object inside itself valid for the lifetime `'b`, as in `struct T<'b> { t: &'b U }`.

`&'a T<'b>`is thus a reference with lifetime `'a` to a `T<'b>` object.

In the case of the `ResponseWriter`, it contains references to the `Request` and to the `TcpStream`, whereas the `Request` does not contain any references.